# How to connect each item in the list to a specific URL?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to connect each item in my list to a specific URL, which later is used in the app as a hyperlink.

```
url = URL.from_text(u'https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сульфат_натрия')
better_url = url.replace(scheme=u'https', port=443)
org_url = better_url.click(u'.')

list2 = ['Калия', 'Натрия', 'Магния', 'Аммония', 'Свинца', 'Кальция', 'Кислорода', 'Ртути', 'Диртути', 'Серы', 'Азота', 'Силиката']
popupMenu = OptionMenu(mainframe, tkvar2, *list2)
Label(mainframe, text="Выберите остаток").grid(row=1, column=2)
popupMenu.grid(row = 2, column = 2) 

def callBack():
   Label(mainframe, text=tkvar.get() + ' ' + tkvar2.get() + ' ' + better_url.get(u'узнать больше')).grid(row=4,column=1)


B = Tkinter.Button(root, text ="Создать название", command = callBack)
B.pack()
```

I want to get a hyperlink in an actual app which will give the right link when two different items of the two different lists are chosen and the button is pressed

Answer (score 1):

You can connect the data with a dictionary

```
list2 = ['Калия', 'Натрия', 'Магния', 'Аммония', 'Свинца', 'Кальция', 'Кислорода', 'Ртути', 'Диртути', 'Серы', 'Азота', 'Силиката']

hyperlink_dict = {
    'Калия':hyperlink,
    'Натрия':hyperlink,
    }
```

Or if the links are coming from an external data source, you can do:

```
list2 = ['Калия', 'Натрия', 'Магния', 'Аммония', 'Свинца', 'Кальция', 'Кислорода', 'Ртути', 'Диртути', 'Серы', 'Азота', 'Силиката']

hyperlink_dict = {}
for item in list2:
    hyperlink_dict[item] = hyperlink
```

Hope this helps!